How have other parties responded to the rise of MKP?
Both EFF and MK are breakaways from the ANC (African National Congress). EFF (Economic Freedom Fighters) is Malema's party, whereas MK (Umkhonto we Sizwe Party) is Zuma's.
As a comparison, a party called COPE (Congress of the People) under Lekota broke away from the ANC in 2008, but was to the ANC's right, not a leftist party.
The ANC has unsurprisingly attacked MKP, but how have other parties responded, specifically:
EFF - MKP is occupying similar economic ground. If they are attacking MKP, what are they saying?
IFP - Inkatha Freedom Party. MKP leader Zuma is a Zulu and wants to preserve and extend traditional leadership powers, just like IFP. Have IFP welcomed or attacked MKP, and what did they say?
COPE - Congress of the People. In decline at this point, but its leader Lekota led a split from the ANC when Zuma was ANC leader and president.
I welcome attempts to answer - but please answer with quotes and sources, not 'obviously this person would say xyz'

Thanks for spelling out the acronyms. It is really helpful.
